# SQL: detect invalid points outside an overlapping feature

Tags: sql, intersect, overlapping-features

I am using the latest QGIS software.
I am working on this script for the basic selection of invalid geometry points beyond the overlapping context, and how would I finish writing it in the WHERE clause using the postGIS commands?

```
SELECT *
FROM cougar_sample_points, NM_GMU

WHERE (NOT st_intersection(NM_GMU.geometry, cougar_sample_points.geometry))
```

The current script seems to do the opposite it says, it finds 154 points of 160, those which are within the boundary rather than the 6 outside of it. If I remove the not, I get like over 1000 records, like a crosstab query would.

What do you suggest?

I will want to delete those records after highlighting the selection.

I figured out how to do this in the attributes table just fine, but I want to learn the SQL.

Anyone know where to find good quality SQL documentation on these commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if a point is within polygon A, it is also outside of polygon B. To overcome this, you can use a `where exists` clause to ignore points that are within **any** polygon.

Note that we don't need to compute the intersection (`st_intersection`) itself, we just need to know if they intersect or not (`st_intersects`)

```sql
SELECT *
FROM cougar_sample_points
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 
   FROM NM_GMU
   WHERE st_intersects(NM_GMU.geometry, cougar_sample_points.geometry)
)
```